# 403 forbidden while sending blob message in activemq

Tags: activemq-classic

Hi There i am getting error:

javax.jms.JMSException: PUT was not successful: 403 Forbidden

This is my jmsFactory bean.

```
<bean id="jmsFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
       <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost:60000?jms.blobTransferPolicy.uploadUrl=http://localhost/uploads/" />
       <property name="trustAllPackages" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the BlobMessage bits a valid (reachable) location where the client can upload the message body and the receiver can download it.  The broker doesn't expose a fileserver and anything by default, you should setup something that can handle this bit.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have to deploy activemq-fileserver and it works

Comment: The file server is deprecated due to security vulnerabilities, I'd recommend using something maintained and up to date.

Comment: I check other options but didn't work. could you suggest any one. thanks